# Why does character go into object in game mode of unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added my character to the scene and I have bunch of pieces of wood that he is supposed to jump on. But, when I click go and start him jumping, the lower half of him disappears inside the log. How do I stop that from happening? Ps I am on unity 5.3.4.

Comment: Are your bounding boxes configured properly?

Comment: You might be looking for information about [rigidbodies and colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add properly sized colliders to the wood objects. The boundries of collider should almost match the size and shape of wood Object mesh. Collider boundries  are shown as green lines in scene.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was stupid of me not to think of that.